# How to edit the WooCommerce storefront shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I'm building a child theme of the storefront WooCommerce theme. How do I edit the shop page, I can't seem to find a php template for it. Which files should I look into?

Comment: create a template file make a wordpress page using it and assign that page as a shop page in woocommerce backend

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for how to edit it, not how to make a new page for it.

Comment: you can edit the changes on page depends on your theme structure - @Pim

Comment: Like I said, I'm using the standard Storefront theme from WooCommerce.

Comment: Specifically, what do you want to edit? You would use a child theme to do this. Ref: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/

Comment: I do have a child theme. I'm simply looking for the php template where the shop and products are displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not find the template files inside StoreFront Theme as they are altering the shop pages using hooks and you can find those hooks inside

**inc>woocommerce>storefront-woocommerce-template-hooks.php**

so if you want to target specific area you need to remove that action and added again with your custom output

for Example Let's Say you want to remove the StoreFront Pagination you can do it as following from your child theme:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'remove_shop_hooks');

function remove_shop_hooks()
{

remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'storefront_woocommerce_pagination', 30);
}
```

**and then you can add your custmized function normally Example:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'testfunc', 10);

function testfunc()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
```

Comment: I deleted everything inside inc>woocommerce>storefront-woocommerce-template-hooks.php
and when I go to my website index. the shop page still comes up and can see products. so this is not it

Answer (score 0):

Storefront does not have it's own file rendering the shop page, it is using hooks to modify the content of the `woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` file inside the plugin directory.